# how to prove the segment $FH=HE$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> Given a right-triangle $\triangle AGC$  $(\angle AGC=90^\circ)$ point $D$ is an arbitrary point on the altitude. $AE=AG$ and $CF=CG$.
>
> How to prove that $FH=HE$?

I found that circles centered at $A$ and $C$ are orthogonal circles. The altitude of triangle $\triangle AGC$ is the radical axis of the 2 circles and the circle of radius $FH$ is tangent to both (green) circles, but I couldn't prove $FH=HE$.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: I'd put the entire thing into Cartesian coordinates with $O(0,0)=G$, $A(0,a),\,C(c,0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**LEMMA:** Extend segment $ED$ until it meets circle with center $A$ and radius $AG$ at point $J$. Draw median $AB'$ of chord $EJ$ until it intersects the radical axis $GK$ at point $B$. Point $B$ is the pole for polar line $EJ$.

**PROOF:** It's easy to see that:

$$\triangle AB'C\sim \triangle AKB,\quad \triangle AKG\sim AGC$$

It means that:

$$\frac{AB'}{AC}=\frac{AK}{AB},\quad \frac{AK}{AG}=\frac{AG}{AC}$$

$$AB'\cdot AB=AK\cdot AC=AG^2$$

It follows that point $B$ is the inverse point of point $B'$ with respect to circle with center $A$ and radius $AG$. By definition point $B$ is the pole for polar line $EJ$. As a consequence, lines $BE$ and $BJ$ (not shown) are tangent to the circle with center $A$.

**End of lemma proof**

[image]

**Back to the main problem:** Construct point $B$ as explained in the lemma. According to lemma proof line $BE$ is tangent to circle with center $A$ and radius $AG$.

Let's do a similar thing for the other circle with center $C$. First, extend line $FD$ until it interesects circle with center $C$ and radius $CG$ at point $L$. Then draw segment $BC$.

Note that point $D$ is the orthocenter of triangle $ABC$ ($BK\perp AC$, $CB'\perp AB$). It follows that $AL\perp BC$. In other words, line $CB$ is the median of chord $FL$.

According to our little lemma it means that point $B$ is also the pole for polar line $FL$. Because of that, line $BF$ is tangent to the circle with center $C$ and radius $CG$.

The rest is trivial. Triangles $BEH$ and $BFH$ are congruent by SSA: $BH=BH$, $BE=BF$ (because point $B$ is on the radical axis of the two circles) and $\angle BEH=\angle BFH=90^\circ$. Therefore:

$$HE=HF$$

Very nice problem, BTW.